# Need to get content database in SharePoint online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, content-database

I need to access a content database's name, and its properties like Size, etc. using CSOM in SharePoint online.

Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 8):

No that is not possible. That layer of the infrastructure is blocked from Global Administrators.

Best you can do is something like:

```
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit all
foreach($site in $sites){ 
    $site.StorageUsageCurrent
}
```

Comment: any other way around it?

Comment: no there isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to Eric's answer (I know the question is related to CSOM) . But manually if you want to check storage usage then you can check it from site setting, admin center as well as from SharePoint designer.

**SharePoint designer.**

[image]

**Admin Center:**

[image]

**Site Setting:**

[image]